# LU-Factorization differs in Lapack and Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, lapack, matrix-factorization

I'm computing a LU-Factorization with Lapack and compare the results. I use either dgetrf or dgetf2. Comparing the results to the corresponding function lu(...) in Matlab, they are identical as long as the the input matrix is square or has more columns than rows. For matrixes with more rows than columns, the values at the bottom right lu-matrix differ. For example, dgetrf and dgetf2 in Lapack for

```
A=[
    1  2  3;
    4  5  6;
    7  8  9;
   10 11 12]
```

gives

```
lu = [
   10.0 11.0    12.0; 
    0.1  0.9     1.8;
    0.7  0.33333 0.0;
    0.4  0.66666 0.45989304812834225]
```

but the same calculated in Matlab results in

```
lu = [
   10.0 11.0    12.0; 
    0.1  0.9     1.8;
    0.7  0.33333 0.0;
    0.4  0.66666 0.0]
```

I have no clue, where difference in the last value of the last row comes from. The same effect is present, when having even more rows.
I'm using Lapack in Swift, but I don't think it has anything to do with the programming language.
Any clue?
Your help is appreciated.

I've tried varying the input parameters of dgetrf and dgetf2, but still the same effect.

Comment: From Matlab R2015b help:
"Y = lu(A) returns the output from LAPACK'S DGETRF or ZGETRF routine if A is full. If A is sparse, Y contains the strict lower triangle of L embedded in the same matrix as the upper triangle of U. In both full and sparse cases, the permutation information is lost."
Thus the results from Matlab and from Lapack show be identical.

Comment: Interesting... The docs for R2018a are the oldest that they keep online. [There I see](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2018a/matlab/ref/lu.html): *"Y = lu(A) returns matrix Y that contains the strictly lower triangular L, i.e., without its unit diagonal, and the upper triangular U as submatrices. That is, if [L,U,P] = lu(A), then Y = U+L-eye(size(A)). The permutation matrix P is not returned."* In R2018b this function form is no longer documented.

Comment: But obviously, `U+L-eye(size(A))` only works if `A` is square...

Comment: I'm still using Matlab R2015b which gives me the result above. Furthermore I compared the behaviour to Octave which corresponds to Matlab. I contrary, when I use dgetrf or dgetf2 directly from Lapack, I get the discrepancy as mentioned. I use lda = m (rows) as leading dimension of the array. Don't know, if that could be the problem.
You're right about the comment regarding the square matrix, but I think that's an inconsistency of the documentation. dgetrf is not restricted to square matrices anyway.

Comment: So maybe you’re doing something wrong when calling lapack? Something that is causing the last element not being written, or being overwritten after? You’d have to post a [mre] for your Swift code.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some MATLAB m-code to test this on my win PC running R2021a. I also wrote C-code to call the MATLAB LAPACK library directly for dgetrf( ) and dgetf2( ). Here is what I get for results:

```
>> lu_test
A =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
LU =
   10.0000   11.0000   12.0000
    0.1000    0.9000    1.8000
    0.7000    0.3333    0.0000
    0.4000    0.6667    0.4599
LUdgetrf =
   10.0000   11.0000   12.0000
    0.1000    0.9000    1.8000
    0.7000    0.3333    0.0000
    0.4000    0.6667    0.4599
LUdgetf2 =
   10.0000   11.0000   12.0000
    0.1000    0.9000    1.8000
    0.7000    0.3333    0.0000
    0.4000    0.6667    0.4599
```

So the MATLAB lu( ) function produces the same result as calling the MATLAB LAPACK library functions dgetrf( ) and dgetf2( ) directly, and they all have that lower right corner spot filled. Maybe you can compare your code to my code below to help determine what is going wrong at your end.

The m-code:

```
A=[ 1  2  3;
    4  5  6;
    7  8  9;
    10 11 12] 
LU = lu(A)
LUdgetrf = dgetrf(A)
LUdgetf2 = dgetf2(A)
```

The C-code for dgetrf:

```
/* MATLAB mex routine, Calls LAPACK dgetrf routine for LU factoring     */
/* Programmer: James Tursa                                              */

/* Includes ----------------------------------------------------------- */

#include "mex.h"
#include "blas.h"
#include "lapack.h"

/* Gateway ------------------------------------------------------------ */

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mwSignedIndex M, N, LDA, INFO, MN;
    mwSignedIndex *IPIV;
    mxArray *A;
    
    if( nlhs > 3 ) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Too many outputs.");
    }
    if( nrhs != 1 || !mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || mxIsSparse(prhs[0]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[0])
                  || mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[0]) != 2 ) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Need one full real double 2D matrix input.");
    }
    M = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    N = mxGetN(prhs[0]);
    LDA = M;
    MN = M<N ? M : N;
    IPIV = mxMalloc(MN * sizeof(*IPIV));
    A = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[0]);
    dgetrf( &M, &N, mxGetData(A), &LDA, IPIV, &INFO );
    if( INFO ) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("dgetrf returned an error code.");
    }
    if( nrhs <= 1 ) {
        plhs[0] = A;
    } else if( nrhs == 2 ) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("2 outputs not yet implemented.");
    } else {
        mexErrMsgTxt("3 outputs not yet implemented.");
    }
    mxFree(IPIV);
}
```

The C-code for dgetf2:

```
/* MATLAB mex routine, Calls LAPACK dgetf2 routine for LU factoring     */
/* Programmer: James Tursa                                              */

/* Includes ----------------------------------------------------------- */

#include "mex.h"
#include "blas.h"
#include "lapack.h"

/* Gateway ------------------------------------------------------------ */

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mwSignedIndex M, N, LDA, INFO, MN;
    mwSignedIndex *IPIV;
    mxArray *A;
    
    if( nlhs > 3 ) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Too many outputs.");
    }
    if( nrhs != 1 || !mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || mxIsSparse(prhs[0]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[0])
                  || mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[0]) != 2 ) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Need one full real double 2D matrix input.");
    }
    M = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    N = mxGetN(prhs[0]);
    LDA = M;
    MN = M<N ? M : N;
    IPIV = mxMalloc(MN * sizeof(*IPIV));
    A = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[0]);
    dgetf2( &M, &N, mxGetData(A), &LDA, IPIV, &INFO );
    if( INFO ) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("dgetf2 returned an error code.");
    }
    if( nrhs <= 1 ) {
        plhs[0] = A;
    } else if( nrhs == 2 ) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("2 outputs not yet implemented.");
    } else {
        mexErrMsgTxt("3 outputs not yet implemented.");
    }
    mxFree(IPIV);
}
```

The mex compile routine:

```
function compile_lapack(varargin)
libdir = 'microsoft';
lib_blas = fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','lib',computer('arch'),libdir,'libmwblas.lib');
lib_lapack = fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','lib',computer('arch'),libdir,'libmwlapack.lib');
mex(varargin{:},lib_blas,lib_lapack,'-largeArrayDims');
end
```

To compile the mex routines:

```
>> compile_lapack('dgetf2.c')
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
MEX completed successfully.

>> compile_lapack('dgetrf.c')
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
MEX completed successfully.
```

UPDATE -----------------------------------------------------------

Online MATLAB R2023a gives these results:

```
>> LUA = lu(A)
LUA =
   10.0000   11.0000   12.0000
    0.1000    0.9000    1.8000
    0.7000    0.3333         0
    0.4000    0.6667         0
>> LUA(3,3)
ans =
   0
>> LUA(4,3)
ans =
   0
```

So there does appear to be a somewhat recent change in the LU algorithm used that gives an exact 0 for the U(3,3) and L(4,3) spots. Whereas my PC MATLAB R2021a gives:

```
>> LUA(3,3)
ans =
   6.9204e-16
>> LUA(4,3)
ans =
    0.4599
```

Yes, it looks funny, but both answers are "correct" in the sense that these residual values are within what one might expect from simple floating point numerical effects.

Feedback on the MATLAB Answers forum indicates that this change *may* have occurred in the R2022a release.

Comment: Maybe OP has a different LAPACK they're using in C from the one in MATLAB, and you are using the same one? In any case, on my Mac, I get a 0 in the lower right corner when I do `lu(A)`.

Comment: Interesting, `[L,U,P] = lu(A)` gives a row of zeros at the bottom of `U`, so that bottom right element in L can be anything, and the product `P'*L*U` remains equal to `A`. (And the element in the bottom right of the `LU` matrix is the bottom right element of the `U` matrix.)

Comment: Mathematically L(end) may be arbitrary, but numerically there are still residual values in the computations that can affect things. E.g., U(end) is not exactly 0, but is 6.9204e-16 in my test. As long as L(end) is not too big it will not affect the P'*L*U result much. But if you make it too big (e.g., 1e20) then it will. Could be that different LAPACK libraries get slightly different results for these near 0 values (e.g., U(end)) and as a consequence end up computing that "arbitrary" L(end) value differently. Although it looks funny, any small enough L(end) is "correct" in that sense.

Comment: Bottom Line: Both of the answers above for L(end) = 0 or 0.45989304812834225 appear to be "correct" and within what might be expected for floating point computation effects for this particular example. Slightly different LU algorithms might produce what appears to be widely different results for the L(end) spot, but in the context of the overall problem it isn't really an issue.